# Has NASA used a consistent definition of "entry interface"?

Tags: history, reentry

The question "[Orion re-entry velocity: Why is it higher than Apollo?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60997/orion-re-entry-velocity-why-is-it-higher-than-apollo?noredirect=1#comment203228_60997)" has an unstated but critical assumption: that re-entry is measured at the same point for both missions.  The point selected to define "re-entry" is fairly arbitrary: for example, you can orbit with a periapsis below Karman line if your orbit is eccentric enough.

I've been able to find that, for Apollo, "entry interface" was an altitude of 400,000 feet, but I haven't been able to find a definition for Orion (or any other NASA spacecraft).  Has it been consistent over time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s also 400K feet for Orion:

> EI is defined at a geodetic altitude of 400 kft

[*Orion Exploration Mission Entry Interface Target Line*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20160001438/downloads/20160001438.pdf) (Rea, Jeremy R., February 2016) p. 1

...as it was for shuttle:

> Entry interface, the point where the vehicle enters the atmosphere, is considered to occur at an altitude of 400,000 feet, approximately 4,200 nm from the landing site, and at a velocity of approximately 25,000 fps. The orbiter is maneuvered to 0° roll and yaw (wings level) and a 40° angle of attack for entry. The flight control system issues the commands to roll, pitch, and yaw RCS jets for rate damping.

[*Shuttle Crew Operations Manual*](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf) p. 1.1-3

Comment: [And also Apollo](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/26day9-reentry.html). That 400 kft definition of EI is a bit arbitrary, but is consistently so.

Comment: 400 kft for Apollo is stated in the question, although unsourced.